# Python two similar dictionary string values. Both return True when tested with two different 'if' tests

Tags: python

When "message = {'CHANGE_KEY': 'EMAIL_ADDRESS_CHANGE'}" it is read by the below if statements and they are True in both. I am looking for a simple solution that does not require modifying all my modules. Double quotes did  not work. Other things caused the program to crash.
My other thought was modifying the value but then it loses its simplicity.

```
message = {'CHANGE_KEY': 'EMAIL_ADDRESS_CHANGE'}

if "EMAIL_ADDRESS_CHANGE" not in message['CHANGE_KEY']: 
    return
else:
    # code, code, code

if 'ADDRESS_CHANGE' not in message['CHANGE_KEY']: 
    return
else:
    # code, code, code
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 4):

You are doing a substring search

ie.

```
'EMAIL_ADDRESS_CHANGE' in 'EMAIL_ADDRESS_CHANGE'
```

and

```
'ADDRESS_CHANGE' in 'EMAIL_ADDRESS_CHANGE'
```

are both true.

Why not test for equality instead?

```
if "EMAIL_ADDRESS_CHANGE" != message['CHANGE_KEY']:
    return
else:
    # code, code, code

if 'ADDRESS_CHANGE' != message['CHANGE_KEY']:
    return
else:
    # code, code, code
```